# consulta de hora en oracle sql para convertir numero en formato hora

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

hola buenas tardes mi pregunta es  tengo una columna con tipo de dato numerico, ejemplo(1234) y deseo que al hacer una consulta me devuelva el fotmato en horas 12:34 saben como podria hacerlo? ya he buscado mucho sin exito

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: tengo una tabla y dentro hay una columna de tipo numerico (1234) con datos como este,deseo que al hacer la consulta a esa tabla me devuelva un campo asi 12:34 como si fuera la hora es todo saludos

Comment: Prueba con `substr()`: `SELECT substr(1234,1,2)||':'||substr(1234,2,2) FROM dual`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con el tipo de dato **TIMESTAMP** (fecha mas precisa), especificando el dato y y el formato en el que lo requieres, ejemplo:

```
SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP(CAMPO,'hh24:mi:ss')HORA FROM TABLA;
```

esta sentencia te devuelve la fecha y la hora de esta manera:

```
01/08/22 12:34:00.000000000
```

También puedes realizarlo de esta manera, dándole formato tu mismo, en donde especificas la posición de la cadena a extraer y la cantidad de digitos, ejemplo:

```
SELECT substr(CAMPO,1,2)||':'||substr(CAMPO,3,2)HORA FROM TABLA;
```

esta sentencia te devuelve la hora de esta manera:

```
12:34
```

Dime si te sirvió.

Comment: la seguna si me sirvio amigo muchisimas gracias hermano

Comment: No olvides aceptar la respuesta o darle en la flecha hacia arriba para indicar que la pregunta a sido resuelta.